# Writing a pandas dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to write a pandas data frame to a CSV file.
However, the last line of my code outputs following error.

> 'PRN' is the name of the ticker
>  {FileNotFoundError}[Errno 2] No
>   such file or directory: G:\\stock_data/daily/PRN.csv

I already checked that the folder "G:\stock_data\daily" exists.

The issue seems that 'PRN' is a reserved name in windows for Printer.
Is there a way that i can save a csv like PRN.csv?
https://superuser.com/questions/613313/why-cant-we-make-con-prn-null-folder-in-windows

```
data = None
usbPath = 'G:\stock_data'
startDate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=70)
    try:
        data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start=startDate, progress=False, interval="1d")
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    for ticker in tickers:      
         dic = {'Open': data['Open'][ticker], 'High': data['High'][ticker], 'Low': data['Low'][ticker], 'Close': data['Close'][ticker]}
         df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
         df.to_csv(os.path.abspath(usbPath) + '/daily/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
```

Comment: I think you might have a problem in the directions of the slashes

Comment: You used `/` instead of ` \ ` in the filename. This would work on Linux, but you appear to use Windows. Try `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(usbPath), 'daily', '{}.csv'.format(...))`. It creates the path correctly on different operating systems

Comment: take a look at the filepath G:\\stock_data/daily/PRN.csv . Seems to me that your slashes got mixed up

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join`

**Ex:**

```
import os

usbPath = r'G:\stock_data'   #Note r in front of windows path 

df.to_csv(os.path.join(usbPath, "daily", '{}.csv'.format(ticker)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the most common mistake regarding this topic, it is a syntax error, if you change it to:

```
usbPath= 'G:/stock_data'
```

it will work